Plotly Heatmap has Limit on Data Size
I’m trying to create a (very) large heatmap using plotly. My dataset is of shape (10, 85000), and I noticed that I can’t display heatmaps when the row size is greater than 65k:
row_size = 65000  # change this to 66000 and the figure is displayed empty
z = np.random.randint(0, 101, size=(10, row_size))
heatmap = go.Heatmap(z=z,
                     colorbar=dict(
                         thickness=25,
                     ))
fig = go.Figure(data=[heatmap])
fig.update_layout(width=1500, height=500)
fig.show()

Is there a way to increase this limit?

No. This limitation is actually the maximum canvas size, which depends on the browser and environment.

Exceeding the maximum dimensions or area renders the canvas unusable —
drawing commands will not work (MDN).

The table below is generated using https://jhildenbiddle.github.io/canvas-size :
Desktop



Browser (OS)
Max Width
Max Height
Max Area (Total)




Chrome 73+ (Mac, Win)
65,535
65,535
16,384 x 16,384 (268,435,456)


Chrome < 73 (Mac, Win)
32,767
32,767
16,384 x 16,384 (268,435,456)


Edge 80+ (Mac, Win)
65,535
65,535
16,384 x 16,384 (268,435,456)


Edge 15 - 18 (Win)
16,384
16,384
16,384 x 16,384 (268,435,456)


Firefox 122+ (Mac, Win)
32,767
32,767
23,168 x 23,168 (536,756,224)


Firefox < 122 (Mac, Win)
32,767
32,767
11,180 x 11,180 (124,992,400)


IE 11 (Win)
16,384
16,384
8,192 x 8,192 (67,108,864)


IE 9 - 10 (Win)
8,192
8,192
8,192 x 8,192 (67,108,864)


Safari 5+ (Mac)
4,194,303
8,388,607
16,384 x 16,384 (268,435,456)



Mobile



Browser (OS)
Max Width
Max Height
Max Area (Total)




Chrome 91+ (Android 8 - 11)
65,535
65,535
16,384 x 16,384 (268,435,456)


Chrome 91+ (Android 7)
65,535
65,535
14,188 x 14,188 (201,299,344)


Chrome 91+ (Android 6)
65,535
65,535
16,384 x 16,384 (268,435,456)


Chrome 91+ (Android 5)
65,535
65,535
11,180 x 11,180 (124,992,400)


Chrome 68+ (Android 7.1 - 9)
32,767
32,767
14,188 x 14,188 (201,299,344)


Chrome 68+ (Android 6)
32,767
32,767
10,836 x 10,836 (117,418,896)


Chrome 68+ (Android 5)
32,767
32,767
11,402 x 11,402 (130,005,604)


IE (Windows Phone 8.x)
4,096
4,096
4,096 x 4,096 (16,777,216)


Mobile Safari 9+
4,194,303
8,388,607
4,096 x 4,096 (16,777,216)



